# Difference between $(this).find("li") and $("li", $(this))

Tags: jquery

While creating a jQuery plugin I find many uses of

```
var obj = $(this);     
$("li:even", obj)
```

to select the current Item. How does this work? Because while writing jQuery snippets I used to write

```
 $(this).find("li");
```

Can someone explain for better understanding? Reference to this code is [here](http://www.queness.com/post/112/a-really-simple-jquery-plugin-tutorial/page/2#comments).

Comment: It's the same thing, the context selector uses find() internally. If it's inside a plugin, there's no need to wrap `this`.

Comment: @adeneo: Re `this`, it depends entirely on where it's being used. Quite common in a plug-in to use `each`, and of course within the iteration function, you'd need to use `$()` on `this` if you wanted to access jQuery functions.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - of course, it's only a jQuery object in the plugins scope, in the scope of for instance a `return this.each()..` etc. that would'nt work. Was just pointing it out, so many people seem to rewrap jQuery objects.

Comment: @adeneo: They do indeed...

Answer (score 4):

The two do the same thing. In fact, if you dig deep enough, you'll find that `$("li:even", obj)` ends up calling `obj.find("li:even")`.

You probably know that (that variant of) the [`$()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) looks up elements in the DOM. The form that accepts that second argument just gives it a starting point, telling it to only look for descendants of the elemnts in the jQuery set you provide as the second argument. Which is, of course, what `find` does.

I remember seeing a comment from one of the jQuery main devs on an issue ticket that they're considering dropping the version of `$()` that accepts the starting point.

Comment: Do you know why they want to drop it? I've always preferred it over `.find()`.

Comment: @Juhana: API and code simplification, if memory serves. `$()` is far too overloaded, which A) Makes it hard to understand, and B) Means its code has to do lots of checks on the arguments (including their types) passed into it before it knows what to do.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - Thanks for your response. It was very useful and informative

Answer (score 3):

> $("li:even", obj)

In the above statement the `context` is passed to selector. This is equalent to `$(this).find("li:even");`

According to jQuery documentation the syntax for selector is [jQuery( selector [, context ] )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

*All the four will bring the same result.*

```
var obj = $(this);
$("li:even", obj)
```

*or*

```
$("li:even", this)
```

*or*

```
$("li:even", $(this))
```

*or*

```
$(this).find("li:even");
```